# Can we optimize CSS hover property?

Tags: css, optimization

Based on the bellow code:

```css
#my-product .description {display: block;}
#my-product .description .complement {display: none;}

#my-product .description:hover .complement {display: block;text-decoration: underline;font-size: 17px;}
#my-product .description:hover .complement img {display: block;border: 1px solid #cccccc;}
#my-product .description:hover .complement hr {display: block;border: 1px solid #cccccc;}
```

Does declaring style in the hover section matter for performance or should we declare it before like this:

```css
#my-product .description {display: block;}
#my-product .description .complement {display: none;text-decoration: underline;font-size: 17px;}
#my-product .description .complement img {display: block;border: 1px solid #cccccc;}
#my-product .description .complement hr {display: block;border: 1px solid #cccccc;}

#my-product .description:hover .complement {display: block;}
```

I'm not asking about code readability but only browser performance.

---

**EDIT** To clarify my question:

In the first example will the browser have to rebuild entirely each elements prefixed by `.description:hover` on each hover made by the user on the description ? Or will he only process `display: none` and `display: block`?

And if he needs to rebuild entirely the description element, does declaring the other styles outside of the `:hover` will optimize this process?

This question is not about selector optimization but only about rendering performance.

Comment: I like the :hover state to be minimal, it's a personal preference - not sure about performance.

Comment: Try to write in a cleaner way i.e in a few words and you will have no problem..! also try to avoid using properties which could make conflict with each other..!

Comment: Avoid writting code for each element in a separate line you can simply add the same css to multiple elements by mentioning them like this way as : `h1,h2,h3 { /*CSS goes here*/ }`